# Bulk-convert non-UTF-8 and UTF-8-with-BOM files to UTF-8

Tags: bash, text, utf-8, character-encoding

Heey i'm trying to create new files with the `find` command in bash on Ubuntu.

I can easily list the files and know how to create a new file from it however i don't want the encoding to come with it.

Right now i'm using this command: `find ./Polish\ 2\ \(copy\)/ -name '*.txt' -type f -exec sh -c 'cat <"$0" >"$0.txt"' {} \;`
however if a file is for example not in UTF-8 format i'd still want to write the new file `$0.txt` in a UTF-8 format.

I came upon this idea since whenever i'm doing this manually:

1. I open the nonUTF8 file in gedit.
2. Copy the contents.
3. Create a new blank file.
4. Open it with gedit.
5. Paste the copied contents to the file and save

The default behavior of gedit is saving to UTF8 in my case. However with over 30.000 files to do this to i don't want to do this manually..

Any solutions with default builtin tools?

## EDIT

The file may be edited on the fly instead of creating a seperate file like i did in my example.

Also what does happen when trying to convert the file with `iconv` if the file is already in `UTF-8` format?

## EDIT 2.0

I'd love to have all the files in the end without `BOM`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no unambiguous method for identifying a file's character encoding by its contents alone, so the best you can do is to assume the most *likely* input encoding ([`CP1252`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), as you state) when you convert to UTF-8, using [`iconv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/iconv.html); to avoid converting files that already *are* UTF-8-encoded, you can use [`file`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html) to detect them:

<sup>Note: For simplicity, I've changed `find`'s target directory to `.`</sup>

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c '
  descr=$(file -b "$0")
  if [[ $descr != *UTF-8* ]]; then
    iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 "$0" > "$0.$$" && mv "$0.$$" "$0"
  elif [[ $descr == *"with BOM"* ]]; then
    tail -c +4 "$0" > "$0.$$" && mv "$0.$$" "$0"
  fi
' {} \;
```

<sup>Note: If you convert this command to a *single-line*-statement, you'll need *additional* `;` instances, namely, *after*:

the `descr=...` statement, the `iconv ...` statement, and the `tail ...` statement.</sup>

Note:

- `file`'s `-b` option is not POSIX-compliant and the standard also doesn't prescribe mentioning a file's *encoding*  or *BOM presence* in the output.
  In practice, however, the above should work on both Linux and macOS/BSD systems.
- A UTF-8 "BOM" (Unicode signature, as used primarily on *Windows*) is 3 bytes long, so if it is detected in the input file via `-file`, `tail -c +4` *skips it*, outputting a "BOM-less" UTF-8 file.